# Antenna House XSL-FO Extensions not working?

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

Any attempt to use Antenna House's xsl-fo extensions by pointing to their namespace (which gives a "page not found" btw) results in an error:

> The element 'root' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format' has invalid child element 'document-info' in namespace 'http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions'. List of possible elements expected: 'layout-master-set' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format'.

It appears that there's some type of namespace referencing issue where the elements in the xsl-fo namespace don't recognize that the extension elements are valid child elements?

Code looks like such:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
     xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
     xmlns:axf='http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions'>
    <xsl:template match='/root'>
        <fo:root xmlns:fo='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format' xmlns:axf='http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions'>
            <axf:document-info name='title' value='value' />
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Funny that they have an example listed on their website that looks exactly the same here:  http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/axf4-extension.htm#axf.document-info

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working with v4.3 of their xsl formatter.

Comment: For the record, a namespace URI such as `http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions` does not have to resolve to anything.  The 'Namespaces in XML' Rec (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl) includes "It is not a goal that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists)." (Exactly what it should resolve to if it does resolve to something is a whole separate discussion.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the issue might be that the xsl-fo is not complete. Does the error occur when transforming the XML to XSL-FO or does it occur when processing the XSL-FO?

Also, I don't think you need to add the namespaces to the `fo:root` element if they're in `xsl:stylsheet`. This might be specific to the XSL processor though. (I'm using Saxon.)

I don't have any experience with Antenna House, but I use RenderX that has similar extensions.

Here's an example of an XML file, XSL stylesheet, and the resulting XSL-FO. (Which works fine in RenderX.)

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root/>
```

**XSL stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <fo:root>
      <rx:meta-info>
        <rx:meta-field name="title" value="Some Title"/>
        <rx:meta-field name="author" value="DevNull"/>
        <rx:meta-field name="subject" value="Some Subject"/>
        <rx:meta-field name="keywords" value="abc def ghi jkl"/>
      </rx:meta-info>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
         xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions">
   <rx:meta-info>
      <rx:meta-field name="title" value="Some Title"/>
      <rx:meta-field name="author" value="DevNull"/>
      <rx:meta-field name="subject" value="Some Subject"/>
      <rx:meta-field name="keywords" value="abc def ghi jkl"/>
   </rx:meta-info>
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
         <fo:region-body/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block/>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

I think if you swap the renderx extensions (`rx:`) for the antenna house extensions, it should work. Maybe you should try rendering the XSL-FO first before trying to generate the XSL-FO using XSL-T.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This was my fault.  There was an xsd schema file that I wasn't aware of.  We ended up having to use the "any" element in the root and block nodes in order to get the template to access the antennahouse extentions.

```
<xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any namespace="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions" processContents="skip"/>
...

<xs:element name="block">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:any namespace="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions" processContents="skip"/>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**focheck** (https://github.com/AntennaHouse/focheck) releases include a W3C XSD for XSL 1.1 plus Antenna House extensions.